# Root Access After Custom ROM Flash

Tags: cyanogenmod, root-access, custom-roms

I have flashed Custom ROM on my S3 Neo using CWM recovery.
Now after flashing the rom,I want to get the root access,so I tapped on the build number several times and activated the developer options,where I get an option of enabling root access.I enabled it for Apps and ADB.Naturally I expected root access after this,but unfortunately while checking by root checker(several best root checkers in play store) whether I got root access or not,it says no su found,and no root access.
What should I do now?Am I to Root the device again? Is it safe??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to flash the whole ROM again.You can just flash the superuser.zip from the recovery.(It's completely safe,just make sure that it's for your device). Good luck!

[Here](http://[Here][1]) is the direct download link for updated supersu.zip from XDA Developers. Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry,the link you provided is blank..

Comment: here try this! http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s3-neo/development/root-samsung-galaxy-s3-neo-t2907189

Comment: Sorry to say that this didn't work..

Comment: Is it possible to get root access on a phone run by cyanogenmod by the rooting application kingo root??
Actually root access is denied,even after the update of super su.

Comment: Well I had S3, a year ago and tried the flash of supersu.zip which worked fine for me. You can always one click root methods. Hope works! If not you can find the rom with pre-root access and flash that. Your recovery does the flashing stuff so rooting is not required (As of my case in my current phone - Moto g 2014).